# Getting string from what appears to be a hash-map in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

In PowerShell, I do this command:

```
$w = iwr -usedefaultcredentials -uri http://acme.corp/anvils.aspx -method 'POST' -Body '{"ctl00_MainEntityNumber:"Wiley"}'
```

That returns an object, part of which is an object called InputFiles, one of which is an object called __VIEWSTATE.  I want to get the string value of __VIEWSTATE.  So I do this:

```
$f = $w.inputfields | where id -eq __VIEWSTATE | select-object value | select-string value
```

which gives me a MatchInfo object.  If I just print out the object, I get

```
@{value=/wEPDwUJODU5MDM5MTc0DxYEHhBQYWdlRW50aXR5TnVtYmVyZh4Yb0luc3VyYW5jZVNlYXJjaENyaXRlcmlhMv0BAAEAAAD/////AQAAAAAAAAAMAgAAAFFJRE9JLlJlZ3VsYXRlZEV ....}
```

which looks to me like a Hashmap or something.  But when I try $f.value or $f['value'] I get nothing, or if I $f[0], I get the whole thing (including the @{value=.. part)  So the question is, how do I get just the string after the @{value=\ ?  Do I have to parse it out manually?

Comment: Remove select string and add -ExpandProperty to select object

Comment: Yeah, `...| select-object value | select-string value` -> `...| Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value`

Comment: Thanks, that works.  Make it an answer and I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just wanting the value itself then change it to

```
$f = $w.inputfields | where id -eq __VIEWSTATE | Select-Object -ExpandProperty value
```